# React- Image is not visible in Styled Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am actually trying to make a Card with Image as a background.
I am doing it using styled components by passing **{imgurl}** as a prop but it is not loading.

**This is my App.Js**

```js
import React from "react";
// import NavBar from "./NavBar";
import DestCard from "./Card";
import { Grid } from "@mui/material";
// import MidPage from "./Midpage";

const cardInfo = [
    {
        image: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bf/LeBron_James_-_51959723161_%28cropped%29.jpg",
        title: "Lebron James",
        text: "THE GOAT",
    },
    {
        image: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/aa/TechCrunch_Disrupt_2019_%2848834853256%29_%281%29.jpg",
        title: "Stephen Curry",
        text: "3 pointer GOD",
    },
    {
        image: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bf/LeBron_James_-_51959723161_%28cropped%29.jpg",
        title: "Lebron James",
        text: "THE GOAT",
    },
    {
        image: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/aa/TechCrunch_Disrupt_2019_%2848834853256%29_%281%29.jpg",
        title: "Stephen Curry",
        text: "3 pointer GOD",
    }
];

function App() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Grid container spacing={{ xs: 2, md: 3 }} columns={{ xs: 4, sm: 8, md: 12 }}>
                {cardInfo.map((details, index) => (
                    <Grid item xs={2} sm={4} md={4} key={index}>
                        <DestCard details={details.image} />
                    </Grid>
                ))}
            </Grid>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App;
```

**This is Card.Js**

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { StyledCard, CardImage } from './Card.style.js';


function DestCard({imgurl}) {
    return(
        <StyledCard>
            <CardImage bg= {imgurl}>

            </CardImage>
        </StyledCard>
    )
}

export default DestCard;
```

**This is the styling file**

```js
import styled from "styled-components";

export const StyledCard= styled.div`
    display: flex;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px -5px;
`

export const CardImage= styled.div`
    /* grid-area: image; */
    /* display: flex; */
    background-image: url(${({bg}) => bg});
    width: 60px;
    /* background-size: cover; */
`
```

I have used the props in Styled Components available here [props in styled component](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#passed-props)

This is the output

[image]

If someone could resolve this it would be really helpful. Thankyou

Comment: `height` of the component CardImage = 0, so cannot see bg. let's add height = 20px (or any)

Comment: thankyou! for your help. It was some other problem I fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In React, whatever name you are passing from parent component should be used in child component.

eg:- you are passing it as details in parent component `<DestCard details={details.image} />` so it should be received as `function DestCard({details})`
in child component

The below code should work

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { StyledCard,CardImage } from './Card.style.js';


function DestCard({details}) {

    return(
        <StyledCard>
            <CardImage bg= {details}>

            </CardImage>
        </StyledCard>
    )
}

export default DestCard
```

Please add appropriate height and width to image properties to view the image in the card